# Firebase in frontend or backend

Tags: firebase

I read firebase is referred to as `backend as a service`, but in its documentation it supports Nodejs. Java, Python, Golang, etc along with Web, Android, and IOS

My question is why do we need backend if firebase itself is a backend as a service.

Comment: what do you mean? how are you comparing //java, Python, Golang// with firebase. Firebase is not a language sir, its a library, for backend, you are using this library using /java, Python, Golang// and so on. That doesn't make it an entire language.

Comment: I meant, Firebase provides Backendas as a service, you can directly have firebase SDK in your client, so why one will need to integrate it in Backend languages like Java, Python, etc, hope this makes sense

Answer (score 2):

Incase your requirements exceed what firebase offers out of the box, firebase will still give you the ability to manage your data in programmatically.

For most use cases, you won't need your own backend. But in some cases you will for example need a custom sign-in flow, or perhaps a custom dashboard to manage firebase users. In those cases firebase gives you the flexibility to do so using the firebase admin SDK, which I believe is being referred to when they list 'Nodejs. Java, Python, Golang' as supported languages.

Checkout the firebase admin documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to understand what you can accomplish using it. Depending on your needs, you might not need it at all.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested to interact, from some backends that you own/control (e.g. a server in your premises), with some Firebase services hosted in the cloud in the Firebase infrastructure.

This can be interesting, for example, to integrate some of your legacy applications with Firebase.

You’ll find [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hlxby1Mmic8) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlmizBWJk6A) two videos from Firebase that show some real life examples.